# How to listening bluetooth LE stop scan devices on Android 4.3

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

When bluetoothLE stop, I want to handle some data. I just searched that the Action "android.bluetooth.adapter.action.DISCOVERY_STARTED" to listen broadcast about bluetooth startDiscovery(), but it do not work on bloothLe scanLeDevice().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no related callback to scanLeDevice, just do your work immediately after calling stopLeScan

Comment: I used stopLeScan() , then started connecting the device that i tested. But not success  always.

Comment: Use Handler.postDelayed to delay the connection after the device is being scanned. BTW, I also thought that scanning will make the connection fail before, but later I found that there were other reasons. For now I can connect to devices without any problem even I am scanning , using N7 2013.

Comment: Thanks for you answers! Could you tell me what factors interference in connectiong Gatt.

Comment: If you start connection immediately after scan, when you scan multiple devices in a short period, you will call connectGatt before other connectGatt finish. The SDK does not accept that.